# Как выполнить команду записанную в переменной из консоли?

Tags: javascript

Хочу иметь возможность при нужде выполнять консольные команды с помощью чата, как это можно организовать? Для примера беру /console console.log('Привет'), но консоль пуста.

```
bot.command('/console', async (msg) => {

let id = ''
let text = msg.message.text;
let command = text.substring(text.indexOf("/console") + 9); // --> console.log('Привет')
  
if (msg.message.from_id === id) {command}
  else {msg.reply('Вы не создатель!')}
})
```

Comment: А в условии у вас опечатка, да? Присваиваете идентификатор, но не сравниваете

Comment: Вы про `msg.message.from_id = id` ? Да, опечатался немного. Поправил, всё так же думаю как выполнить.

Comment: надо понимать как работать с async/await .... наверняка ты смотришь в консоль за пределами bont.command